# Integers with a Hamiltonian Square Path

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-paths

Let $n>1$ be an integer and set $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. We say that $n$ has a "Hamiltonian Square Path" if there is a bijection $\varphi:[n]\to[n]$ such that for all $k\in [n-1]$ we have that $\varphi(k)+\varphi(k+1)$ is a square number.

For instance $15$ and $16$ have this property.

**Question.** Is there an integer $N>1$ such that every integer $n\geq N$ has a Hamiltonian Square Path?

---

**Note.** This problem can be formulated in the language of graph theory and [Hamiltonian paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). We say that $a\neq b\in [n]$ form an edge if their sum is square, and the above question is about integers such that the resulting graph has a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: A closely related mathoverflow question: (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199677) with some numerical results.

Comment: The following puzzle by Freddy Barrera and Carlos Zuluaga (Colombia Aprendiendo) is based on these ideas: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57093/integers-around-a-circle-with-consecutive-pairs-adding-to-a-square

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post #22 at https://mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?p=477787 by R. Gerbicz claims a proof that $N=25$ is the answer, and that for $N\ge32$ there is a Hamiltonian cycle. See also the tabulation and discussion at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A090461).