# Generalisation of this circular arrangement of numbers from $1$ to $32$ with two adjacent numbers being perfect squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

I posted this question on MSE, and failed to get the type of answer I wanted. That's why I would like to post it here and wait for the experts to reply. [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289064/generalisation-of-this-circular-arrangement-of-numbers-from-1-to-32-with-two) the link to the MSE post, which I anyways copy paste here as well-

> I got this interesting arrangement of numbers from $1$ to $32$ in a group in Facebook-
> [image]
>
> This being an interesting property to look at, I was trying to figure out whether $32$ is something special, or does this hold for other numbers as well. So, let's say, we want to construct one such circle for a general $n$. My idea was to take any $m\in \mathbb N_n=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ and find two different integers $x,y\in\mathbb N_n$ so that both $(m+x)$ and $(m+y)$ are perfect squares. Then, we need to find $x^\prime, y^\prime\in \mathbb N_n$ different from $x$, $y$ and $m$ such that both $(x+x^\prime)$ and $(y+y^\prime)$ are perfect squares. Then, we can continue in this manner.
>
> Now, for any two $a,b\in \mathbb N_n$, we have $2\leq a+b\leq 2n$. So, for our given $m$, when we are looking for the mentioned $x$ and $y$, we only need to check through all the perfect squares in the interval $[m,2n]$. So, to reduce our work, we can take our initial choice $m$ to be equal to $n$.
>
> But, now comes the main problem. Let's say, we want to work it out for $\mathbb N_{33}$. So, let's say, our initial $m$ is $33$. The values of $x$ and $y$ can be from the set $\{3,16,31\}$. The question is, which two of these three to choose so that eventually we don't run into a repitition. Note that, in the $\mathbb N_{32}$ case (which is the one in the diagram), taking $m=32$ leaves us with an advantage of having only two choices $4$ and $17$. But, in the next step, for finding the appropriate $x^\prime$ for $x=4$, we have the choices $\{5,12,21\}$ (since $32$ is already taken). The given diagram uses $x^\prime =21$. I tried using $x^\prime =5$ and then using values of my choice, but soon ran into an unavoidable repitition.
>
> So, is there a way to make more circles with other values of $n$, or does $32$ have some profound property which makes it the only possible choice for $n$? I thought, maybe $32$ being a power of $2$ has to do something with it. So, I tried using $n=2,4,8,16$. But, these are trivially NOT solutions since there aren't enough perfect squares in $[n,2n]$ for these values of $n$. Note that this "not enough squares" angle immediately gives a lower bound of $n\geq 19$ by trial and error. As Peter Taylor pointed out, this "not enough squares" argument also rules out $n\le 30$ since $18$ is always a vertex of degree $1$ otherwise. So, we have a lower bound of $n\ge 31$. Also, I was too lazy to even attempt $n=64$.
>
> So, is this case a rare coincidence, or can we have other values of $n$ satisfying this property as well? If there are other values, what family do they belong to? Also, for any case, is that arrangement unique?
>
> **Edit:** I got one interesting answer that uses graph theory. But, that has a computer program to check that it holds for all $100\geq n\geq 32$. However, I want more "mathy" arguments. I want to see why this happens instead of to only confirm that it happens. I want to know whether it happens for all $n$ or whether there are cases where it breaks down. Please consider these questions as well.

One answer I got is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4289090/943723) which (as I already mentioned) is only good enough to check using a computer program that our desired property holds for $100\geq n\geq 32$. But, it does provide a very nice insight into the question using Graph Theory in terms of Hamiltonian cycles. So, added to the questions I asked in the "Edit" paragraph of the main post, one more question I would like to ask on this platform is, **has there been any formal research on this topic?** That is, are there any papers dealing with finding Hamiltonian cycles in this particular case? If yes, please let me know.

Comment: The "not enough squares" argument rules out $18 \le n \le 30$ because $18$ pairs with $7$ and then nothing below $31$.

Comment: Let $X_n$ denote the $n$-vertex instance of this graph. Then $X_{n+1}$ is obtained from $X_n$ by adding vertex $n+1$ and has  a Hamilton cycle if (and only if) there is a Hamilton *path* in $X_n$ starting and ending at distinct neighbours of $n+1$. So I asked the computer about Hamilton paths in $X_n$. For $n$ around $30$-$40$ there are quite a few pairs of vertices that are not connected. Strangely though, for $n$ at least 51 up to 70, there is a *unique* pair of vertices (always 14 and 31) that are not connected by a Hamilton path in $X_n$. So $X_n$ is very close to being Hamilton connected.

Comment: In fact, for $n > 70$ and up to $85$, the graph is Hamilton connected, and I expect this to continue. But I can't see any obvious way of using this inductively.

Comment: Related discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168983/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676413/for-which-n-can-1-2-n-be-rearranged-so-that-the-sum-of-each-two-adja and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601161/numberphiless-square-sum-problem and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241530/the-square-sum-problem-v2-0 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313999/name-or-oeis-entry-for-a-certain-set-of-numbers and others.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I can understand that the "not enough squares" argument rules out $n=18$ as I have already mentioned in the post. But, I can't see how it rules out $19\le n\le 30$. For example, for $n=19$, we can pair it with both $x=6$ and $y=17$. Can you please explain a little more... sorry for the late reply btw

Comment: @GordonRoyle Can you maybe add more elaborations to your comment and post it as an answer... Those seem to be nice observations. But, as you mentioned, we don't seem to have an obvious way to extend it for all $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the comment, but I have previously seen all these links. The thing is, all of them more or less talk about events rather than their explanation. Yes, we can use a computer program to see what's happening, but that doesn't explain how it's happening. I am more interested in the how of the scenario.

Comment: @SayanDutta Peter Taylor's observation is that for $n$ between 19 and 30, the vertex "18" is a vertex of degree 1 in the graph and so cannot be contained in a cycle.

Comment: @GordonRoyle oh yes! That's a very beautiful observation! I should add that to the post.

Comment: The links were not there just for you, Sayan, but for anyone wanting to see what kind of work had already been done, so no one reinvents the wheel. And, anyway, there was no indication in your post, was there, that you had read all those links (and the links at those links). If there is anything else that you have already seen that's related to this question, maybe you could let us know, so no one else tries to tell you things you already know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh yes, sure, I understand that. I didn't mean to be harsh. I'm sorry if I sounded rude.

Comment: Not to worry, Sayan. No harm, no foul.

Comment: Related: [Integers with a Hamiltonian Square Path](https://mathoverflow.net/q/332461) and [Arranging numbers from 1 to $n$ such that the sum of every two adjacent numbers is a perfect power](https://mathoverflow.net/q/199677).

Comment: This graph has at least $C \cdot n^{3/2}$ edges (probably a much more precise estimate can be obtained). There are results saying (roughly) that random graphs with sufficiently many edges have an Hamiltonian cycle with probability tending to 1 when the size tends to infinity. Of course this will prove nothing, but it gives an idea of the answer.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault I'm not familiar with that theorem. Can you maybe provide soe links to read about that a little more...

Comment: See https://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~gbrunet/project2.pdf

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault okay, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one published mention of this problem. Two sequences in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, [A071983](http://oeis.org/A071983) and [A071984](http://oeis.org/A071984), are very relevant.  The entry for A071983 gives a reference:

> Ruemmler, Ronald E., "Square Loops," *Journal of Recreational Mathematics* 14:2 (1981-82), page 141; Solution by Chris Crandell and Lance Gay, *JRM* 15:2 (1982-83), page 155.